# Distance between sets implies completness of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Given the metric space $(X,d)$ suppose that for every nonempty, closed $A,B\subseteq X$ with $$A\cap B=\varnothing, \mathrm{dist}(A, B)>0.$$
>   Show that  $(X,d)$ is complete.

But given the definition of distance as $$\operatorname{dist}(A,B)=\inf\{d(a,b):a \in A,b \in B\}$$ 
and given that  $$A\cap B=\varnothing$$ 
and the fact that $A,B$ are closed 
we have that  $$\mathrm{dist}(A, B)=0\iff A\cap B \neq \varnothing$$


Am I missing something?

Comment: Your last statement is not true. E.g. in $\Bbb R$ with the usual distance, $d((0,1), (1,2)) = 0$, but the intersection is empty

Comment: I ment given that the sets are closed. Thanx for noticing!

Comment: In $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual metric, the sets $[0,\sqrt{2}),(\sqrt{2},5]$ are disjoint, closed, and have distance 0. This happens precisely because the space isn't complete.

Comment: Your if and only if statement is still not true. It holds iff A is compact and B is closed or vice versa. A counterexample for both closed is $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{ n + 1/n : n\in \mathbb{N} \} $

Comment: @Micapps Now I undestand what I was missing, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As Micapps pointed out in the comments, in $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual metric, $[0,\sqrt{2}), (\sqrt{2},5]$ are disjoint closed sets with distance zero, so your last statement is not true.

To show the problem, we show the contrapositive. Let $\{s_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a non-convergent Cauchy sequence of distinct points (which thus has no accumulation point). For each $s_{2n}$, let $B_{2n}$ be an open ball about $s_{2n}$ that does not include any of the other $s_i$ ($i \neq 2n$). (In particular, none of these open balls include any odd-indexed $s_i$.)

Let $A = \{s_{2n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $B = \{x : x\notin B_{2n}$ for any $n\}$, i.e. the complement of the union of the $B_{2i}$. Then $A,B$ are disjoint closed sets with distance $0$.

Comment: Why is the distance zero?

Comment: @AreaMan actually you're right, I need to slightly modify the proof to ensure that. One moment.

Comment: @AreaMan ok I modified the proof appropriately. The distance between the two closed sets is 0 because $B$ contains all of the odd-indexed $s_i$, which since $\{s_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ was a Cauchy sequence, get arbitrarily close to the $s_{2n}$ in $A$.

Comment: I think this can be simplified: suppose $X$ is not complete. Then we can find a Cauchy sequence of points $x_i\in X$ which is *injective* ($i\not=j\implies x_i\not=x_j$) and which does not converge. Now let $A=\{x_{2n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $B=\{x_{2n+1}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. By injectivity, $A\cap B=\emptyset$, and by Cauchyness $dist(A, B)=0$. Closedness of $A$ and $B$, meanwhile, follows from the fact that the sequence $x_i$ does not converge (in particular, a non-convergent Cauchy sequence has no convergent subsequence).

Comment: Quite right Noah.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this statement is true.
For example, the interval $(0,1] \in \mathbb{R}$ seems to has the property from the hypothesis but clearly is not complete.
But I'm not sure if the property is really true on this space.

Comment: $(0, 1]$ does not satisfy the hypothesis: let $A=\{{1\over 4^n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $B=\{{1\over 2\cdot 4^n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A, B$ are closed in $(0, 1]$, but $dist(A, B)=0$.

Comment: You're right!
This example doesn't work.

Comment: I'd like to add that the converse does not hold.E.g with the usual metric on $R$ ,with $A=N$ and $B=\{n+2^{-n}: n\in N\}$.